# SQL Select for each Age Group and COUNT Members

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables

**[Members]**:

```
MemberID   DOB              Name
------------------------------------
1          01/01/2000       Jon
2          01/01/2005       Bob
3          01/01/2009       Mike
4          01/01/1980       Greg
```

**[AgeGroups]**:

```
GroupID      GroupTitle       MinAge    MaxAge
--------------------------------------------------
1            GroupA      0         5
2            GroupB      6         10
3            GroupC      11        18
```

**[Events]**:

```
EventID      EventStart
---------------------------
1            01/01/2015
```

I want to be able to do a SQL select command which gets the Group Title and a count of the number of members who's age will be within the age range of each of the Age Groups at the date of the EventStart.

```
GroupTitle       MemberCount
----------------------------------
GroupA           1
GroupB           2
GroupC           1
```

I've been trying to do this with SELECT CASE WHEN but have got stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Date and Time Data Types and Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx), and in particular at the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

You could try something like the following:

```
SELECT AgeGroups.GroupID, AgeGroups.GroupTitle, COUNT(1) AS MemberCount
FROM AgeGroups
JOIN Events ON EventID = 1
JOIN Members 
ON DATEDIFF(year, Members.DOB, Events.EventStart) >= AgeGroups.MinAge
AND DATEDIFF(year, Members.DOB, Events.EventStart) <= AgeGroups.MaxAge
ORDER BY AgeGroups.GroupID
```

Does that help?

Comment: I'm just working with a new data set and this SELECT query doesn't seem to return any AgeGroups where there are no Members yet. I'd like it to return a full list of AgeGroups even if the COUNT result is zero. I've been trying lots of different things to get this to work but I just can't seem to find the right combination of ISNULL and OUTER JOIN to work - any ideas?

Comment: @Andrew `LEFT JOIN Members` may help you.  Look up outer join documentation to learn how this works.